# How do I limit data returned by Solspace Freeform User Notification Template?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am running Solspace Freeform 4.x for a fairly lengthy volunteer signup form. I would like to provide a record back to the user for those items they sign up up for. However by using the **{all_form_fields_string}** in the notification template I get all fields returned in the email notification whether it has a value associated with it or not. Is there a way to return only those fields that have a value? If so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Freeform control panel you can create a custom [**notification**](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/control_panel/#notifications) and then use conditionals in the notification template.

```
{if your_form_field}
   Your form field is: {your_form_field}
{/if}
```

Just be sure to edit that form's settings in the Freeform control panel and choose that notification template.

Comment: Hi Alex, this looks good. Is there any way to do this universally? I ask only because this particular form has a lot of fields (50+). Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. That would be very nice, but no, not that I know of. A shortcut could be to get the field names with SQL (`SELECT field_name FROM exp_freeform_fields`) and then paste them into Sublime Text and do multi-line editing.